# Hammerjs configuration for pinch zoom in Angular

Tags: angular, hammer.js

I am using HammerJS with Angular 4 application for pinch zoom an image. In hammerJS doc it is mentioned by default pinch zoom is set to off and the code to turn it on is

```
hammertime.get('pinch').set({ enable: true });
```

Could anyone please help me what is angular 4 equivalent of this and what are the other configuration required to use hammer pinch zoom in angular 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is pretty vague. As asked though, the following is most likely what you are looking for:

You first need to perform an npm install in your project to bring in the hammerjs library: `npm install --save hammerjs`

Then in your view/component you need to get a reference to the element you are interested in listening to events on with `hammer.js`.

Below is an example of how you could do that with small modifications on the default project the cli produces.

`app.component.html`

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <img #img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
</div>
<h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

`app.component.ts`

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import * as Hammer from 'hammerjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('img') imgElement: ElementRef;
  title = 'app';

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const hammer = new Hammer(this.imgElement.nativeElement);
    // hammer.on('press', function(e) {
    //   e.target.classList.toggle('expand');
    //   console.log('You\'re pressing me!');
    //   console.log(e);
    // });

    hammer.get('pinch').set({ enable: true });
  }
}
```

Full answer code on [GitHub](https://github.com/PdUi/stack-overflow-answer-repos/tree/master/ng-hammer).

Comment: Thanks! This is what i was looking for.